# Byte copying in C (using memcpy?)

Tags: c

I have a message with 5 bytes with 5 fields (1 byte each). I need to copy the 5th byte to a buffer. How to do it using memcpy?

5 byte is just an eg. this might vary. But as of now, please give a solution with 5 bytes eg. The byte can be either character type or an integer. Preferably character.

Comment: Did you try anything that didn't work ?

Answer (score 4):

```
char message[5] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
char byte5;

memcpy(&byte5, message+4, 1);

printf("Byte #5 is %c\n", byte5);
```

Answer (score -3):

you should first post the ways you tried and where you face difficulty.

However, for example,

```
char buf[5]; /*your message buffer*/
char req_byte;  /*your required byte */
```

you can use memcpy as,

```
memcpy(&req_byte, (buf+4), 1);
```

this will copy fifth byte of your message to req_byte. you can vary number after (+) in source buffer to copy desired byte.

hope it helps....

Comment: You did not allocate any memory to the pointer `req_byte`.  Your `memcpy` will attempt to write to address 0, and seg-fault.

Comment: this is just a demonstration how memcpy can be used, not actual code.